# How to pass pytest fixture to the main function without adding it to parameters?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

In my project I have a `Settings` class:

`config.py`

```
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    DEBUG: bool = os.getenv("DEBUG", 'False')
    TOKEN_KEY: str = os.getenv("TOKEN_KEY", '')
    TOKEN_PASSWORD: str = os.getenv("TOKEN_PASSWORD", '')


@lru_cache()
def get_settings():
    return Settings()
```

And I'm using it in a method like this:

`helpers.py`

```
def generate_new_token(user: User) -> str:
   
    settings = get_settings()
    private_key = settings.TOKEN_KEY
    token_password = settings.TOKEN_PASSWORD
    # Do something
```

I've created these two fixtures:

`conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture
def get_settings():
    return Settings(DEBUG=True, TOKEN_KEY="SOME_FAKE_TOKEN_KEY", TOKEN_PASSWORD='')

@pytest.fixture
def get_user():
    return User()
```

Now I want to test the `generate_new_token` method with the values returned from fixtures:

`test_helpers.py`

```
def test_generate_new_token(get_user, get_settings):
    generate_new_token(user=get_user)
```

In this case, the `TOKEN_KEY` value from `get_settings` should be `SOME_FAKE_TOKEN_KEY`, but it's still empty.

When I debug the code, I can see that it passes the value from `get_settings` fixture to `test_generate_new_token` , but then `generate_new_token` calls the main `get_settings` method and does not use the `get_settings` value from fixture as `settings` value.

I know that if I pass `settings` as a parameter to `generate_new_token` like this:

```
def generate_new_token(user: DexterUser, settings: Settings) -> str:
```

I can then pass the fixture to it from test function:

```
def test_generate_new_token(get_user, get_settings):
    generate_new_token(user=get_user, settings=get_settings)
```

But is there anyway to pass the fixture to the main function without having to add it to its parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixture does not replace the function `get_settings`, it is just another implementation. What you need to do is to *patch* the implementation with your own, for example:

*conftest.py*

```py
from unittest import mock
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def get_settings():
    with mock.patch("your_module.helpers.get_settings") as mocked_settings:
        mocked_settings.return_value = Settings(
            DEBUG=True,                                               
            TOKEN_KEY="SOME_FAKE_TOKEN_KEY",                                               
            TOKEN_PASSWORD='')
        yield
```

Note that you have to mock the reference of `get_settings` that is imported in your `helpers` module, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).